# can not use function as type in Go

Tags: go

I am trying run Ethereum from the sources (I want to trace the execution with a debugger) and I am having problems in compiling it. This is the error I am getting:

```
[niko@localhost sources]$  go run github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/cmd/geth/main.go github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/cmd/geth/config.go github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/cmd/geth/chaincmd.go github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/cmd/geth/monitorcmd.go github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/cmd/geth/accountcmd.go gopkg.in/urfave/cli.v1  --verbosity 5 --ipcdisable --port 40401 --rpc --rpcport 9101 --pprof --datadir=/home/niko/saved-niko-home/myeth/ --networkid=15 console 
# command-line-arguments
github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/cmd/geth/config.go:42: cannot use dumpConfig (type func(*"gopkg.in/urfave/cli.v1".Context) error) as type func(*"github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/vendor/gopkg.in/urfave/cli.v1".Context) error in argument to utils.MigrateFlags
github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/cmd/geth/chaincmd.go:43: cannot use initGenesis (type func(*"gopkg.in/urfave/cli.v1".Context) error) as type func(*"github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/vendor/gopkg.in/urfave/cli.v1".Context) error in argument to utils.MigrateFlags
github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/cmd/geth/chaincmd.go:60: cannot use importChain (type func(*"gopkg.in/urfave/cli.v1".Context) error) as type func(*"github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/vendor/gopkg.in/urfave/cli.v1".Context) error in argument to utils.MigrateFlags
github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/cmd/geth/chaincmd.go:78: cannot use exportChain (type func(*"gopkg.in/urfave/cli.v1".Context) error) as type func(*"github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/vendor/gopkg.in/urfave/cli.v1".Context) error in argument to utils.MigrateFlags
github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/cmd/geth/chaincmd.go:95: cannot use removeDB (type func(*"gopkg.in/urfave/cli.v1".Context) error) as type func(*"github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/vendor/gopkg.in/urfave/cli.v1".Context) error in argument to utils.MigrateFlags
github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/cmd/geth/chaincmd.go:108: cannot use dump (type func(*"gopkg.in/urfave/cli.v1".Context) error) as type func(*"github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/vendor/gopkg.in/urfave/cli.v1".Context) error in argument to utils.MigrateFlags
github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/cmd/geth/monitorcmd.go:52: cannot use monitor (type func(*"gopkg.in/urfave/cli.v1".Context) error) as type func(*"github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/vendor/gopkg.in/urfave/cli.v1".Context) error in argument to utils.MigrateFlags
github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/cmd/geth/accountcmd.go:50: cannot use importWallet (type func(*"gopkg.in/urfave/cli.v1".Context) error) as type func(*"github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/vendor/gopkg.in/urfave/cli.v1".Context) error in argument to utils.MigrateFlags
github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/cmd/geth/accountcmd.go:96: cannot use accountList (type func(*"gopkg.in/urfave/cli.v1".Context) error) as type func(*"github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/vendor/gopkg.in/urfave/cli.v1".Context) error in argument to utils.MigrateFlags
github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/cmd/geth/accountcmd.go:107: cannot use accountCreate (type func(*"gopkg.in/urfave/cli.v1".Context) error) as type func(*"github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/vendor/gopkg.in/urfave/cli.v1".Context) error in argument to utils.MigrateFlags
github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/cmd/geth/accountcmd.go:107: too many errors
[niko@localhost sources]$ 
[niko@localhost sources]$ echo $GOPATH
/home/niko/sources/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/build/_workspace/:/home/niko/sources/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/vendor:/home/niko/go
[niko@localhost sources]$
```

as you can see it complains that:

```
func(*"gopkg.in/urfave/cli.v1".Context)
```

is not the same as:

```
func(*"github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/vendor/gopkg.in/urfave/cli.v1".Context)
```

However, it is the same, because I copied it manually to /home/niko/go where all my `Go` packages reside:

```
[niko@localhost sources]$ find /home/niko/go -iname "*cli.v1*"
/home/niko/go/src/gopkg.in/urfave/cli.v1
/home/niko/go/pkg/linux_amd64/gopkg.in/urfave/cli.v1.a
[niko@localhost sources]$
```

And it is in my GOPATH

So, how do I get around this error, how do I tell Go that the package is the good one ?

Comment: It's not the same, though--the paths are different. That makes them different

Comment: @Flimzy the path where the code is located belongs to Go's standard place where reusable packages should be, i.e. in the GOPATH directory

Comment: That doesn't matter. The code expects it to be vendored. So if it's not in the vendored directory, it's wrong.

Comment: @Flimzy how do I specify exactly where the files must be located?Because I have copied them from one place to another for hours and it doesn't work.

Comment: You shouldn't be copying/moving them at all. The vendored files should come with source package typically.

Comment: How have you installed it and vendored packages? Possibly there's a conflict with libraries with similar names or installed at different time to GOPATH.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/vendor/gopkg.in/urfave/cli.v1`

`gopkg.in/urfave/cli.v1`

are different import path package, no matter the content, they are considered as different.

The problem here is that your program is somehow loading it twice from different locations, leading to the kind of error messages you provided.

I m not so clear about the `go run` command line you used, I d rather do,

```
go run github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/cmd/geth/*go --verbosity 5 --ipcdisable --port 40401 --rpc --rpcport 9101 --pprof --datadir=/home/niko/saved-niko-home/myeth/ --networkid=15 console
```

Unless you want to hack ethereum, i see no reason to copy its dependencies to your gopath.
As they **vendored** their dependencies (IE: they copied their dependencies into the vendor folder) ref: https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/tree/master/vendor you really should use those.

About your gopath

`/home/niko/sources/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/build/_workspace/:/home/niko/sources/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/vendor:/home/niko/go`

It does not looks good to me.

If `GOPATH=/home/niko/sources/`, then,

```
tree $GOPATH -L 1
/home/niko/sources/
├── bin
├── pkg
└── src

3 directories, 0 files
```

And `ls -al $GOPATH/src/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum` should be correct.

see also `go env`.

Comment: Yes, you are totally correct, functions are defined twice, because I feed source files manually in the command line. However, if I omit them I will get another problem which is posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46626072/problems-building-go-code-from-sources

Comment: after laying out the source in src , pkg directories it worked. Thanks!